# Can I have my sound muted when head phones are not plugged in?

Tags: windows-8, audio, speakers, headphones

On my Macbook, I could have different "audio profiles" depending on whether or not headphones were plugged in.  I'd have my speakers on mute, and when I plugged in my headphones it would unmute.  This was great at the office in case any web pages I wasn't supposed to be on suddenly popped up with some video of cats playing piano or what not.

I switched to a new Windows laptop that runs Windows 8.1, however there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  My mute status and volume stays the same regardless of whether or not I have head phones plugged in.

Is there a way to configure Windows to mute the sound unless headphones are plugged in?  Seems like a basic feature.

**Update:**

I have a Realtek HD Audio driver (Stock Windows 8.1 driver).  I've already checked, and the driver does not remember volume levels so I can't just turn the volume all the way down.  However, it does pop up a notification when I plug in headphones telling me that I just plugged in headphones, thus the hardware is capable of telling the difference.

**Update 2:**

I installed the latest drivers from Realtek.  I now have a Realtek HD Audio Manager that pops up when I plug in headphones.  However, it *still* does not remember audio levels *or* mute status when I plug in or unplug headphones, nor can I find any features in the Audio Manager for that sort of thing.  From what I can tell, this is a driver feature and not an OS feature, and my drivers simply don't support that.  Bummer.

Comment: It's a basic feature of SOME sound adapters.  Ensure you have the latest drivers/utilities for yours installed.  Also, instead of remembering mute state, often they'll only remember volume levels.  So instead of setting it to Mute, try turning it down to 0.

Comment: @techie007 - Just checked, it doesn't remember volume level either..  I have whatever drivers Windows 8.1 comes with, but perhaps the hardware manufacturer has something else.